# Python Pillow unknown RAW mode with 24 bit grayscal TIFF image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, tiff

I am trying to convert a 24 bit grayscale Tiff image to JPEG in Python with Pillow. This attempt works for some 24 bit Tiff images, but not all. It gives `unknown raw mode` for the image below:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("example.tif")
if im.mode != "L":  # rescale 16 bit tiffs to 8 bits
    im.mode = "I"
    im = im.point(lambda i: i * (1.0 / 256))
im = im.convert("RGB")
im.save("example.jpg", "JPEG", quality=100)
```

Here's an example of an offending image (which appears to be converted to PNG on upload to the site):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the mode of this example image is already `RGB` even though the image appears to be grayscale. If you don't try manual rescaling first, the pillow conversion works fine:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("example.tif")
if im.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):  # rescale 16 bit tiffs to 8 bits
    im.mode = "L"
    im = im.point(lambda i: i * (1.0 / 256))
im = im.convert("RGB")
im.save("example.jpg", "JPEG", quality=100)
```